# how can i stop my dracaena growing to tall?

Tags: growth

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I had just one dracaena 10 years ago.
But it grew too fast.
Finally It reached to top of the room.
At first, it was not quite a big problem.
Every time when It reaches to top of the room, I cut if half.
Now, I have 10 dracaenas that were came out from one dracaena.
And that is the problem now.
Because they are a lot more than 10 years ago,
I cant afford total "plants growing speed".
Simply calculated the speed, It would be 10 times faster than 10 years ago.
Even though when i cut tip of the plants,another head came out from top.
Eventually it reached to top of the room.Result was the same.
I want to make my plants maintain their form forever.
Is there anything I could do to stop this?
I can't afford any more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some options to deal with it:

1. Sell unused plant offsprings.
2. Cut the very tips and throw them away, for the plant to start branching.
3. Lower temperature and less water usually slow the growth.
4. Sell the whole plant a get a slowly-growing species (definitely not dracaena).

Also, you can cut it to smaller pieces (up to one leaf node to make a thicker bush. 
[image]

Comment: I typed dracaena as dracena. sorry :)
By the way,can i ask 1 questions more?
is there some way to thickening the plants?
i heard that get rid of branches thickening trees.
But i am not sure

Comment: If you cut the tips to make it branch more, the older stems can thicken. It depends on the exact species. Can you attach a picture of your plant?

Comment: Yeah, it will thicken if you keep the base and cut the too regularly. You can also not only cut it in half, but cut to smaller pieces (up to one leaf node) to make a thicker bush.